# Python googleapiclient Append Row With Background Color

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to insert a row into a google sheet while setting a background color.

I've got the append to a new row working fine. From what I've been able to see in the docs backgroundcolor is set as an RGB dictionary but I can't find anything which documents where to do this with the official API. I've tried it in the append call but that doesn't seem to work.

It seems more likely it should be in the body dict but I've tried variations there and I get TypeError responses.

```
range_notation = "Sheet1"
    body = {
        'values': [
            row
        ],
        'backgroundColor' : {'red': 1, 'green': 0, 'blue': 100}
    }

    result = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                                   range=range_notation,
                                   body=body,
                                   valueInputOption="RAW",
                                   insert
```

Tried variations like:

```
body = {
        'values': [
            {
                'userEnteredValue': row,
                'userEnteredFormat': {
                    'backgroundColor': {'red': 100, 'green': 0, 'blue': 0},
                },
            },
        ],

    }
```

but it gets a HttpError from the lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to append a row by putting the values.
- You want to change the background colors of the appended row.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

### Modification point:

- In order to append values and change the background color, the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate in Sheets API is used.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values of 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3' are appended to the sheet as a row and the background color of these cells is modified.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheet_id = '###' # Please set Spreadsheet ID
sheetId = 0 # Please set sheet ID. For example, the 1st sheet ID of the default Spreadsheet is 0.
row = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'] # Please set the values.

values = [{'userEnteredFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 0, 'blue': 100}}, 'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': col}} for col in row]
requests = {'requests': [{'appendCells': {'rows': [{'values': values}], 'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor,userEnteredValue', 'sheetId': sheetId}}]}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=requests).execute()
print(response)
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values of 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3' are appended to the sheet as a row and the background color of the row is modified.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheet_id = '###' # Please set Spreadsheet ID
sheetId = 0 # Please set sheet ID. For example, the 1st sheet ID of the default Spreadsheet is 0.
row = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'] # Please set the values.

ss = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id).execute()
for sheet in ss['sheets']:
    if sheet['properties']['sheetId'] == sheetId:
        row.extend([''] * (sheet['properties']['gridProperties']['columnCount'] - len(row)))
        break
values = [{'userEnteredFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 0, 'blue': 100}}, 'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': col}} for col in row]
requests = {'requests': [{'appendCells': {'rows': [{'values': values}], 'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor,userEnteredValue', 'sheetId': sheetId}}]}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=requests).execute()
print(response)
```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.